# join two table with non-matching rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having two table.

one table contains customer details(i.e)

```
id(customerid--primary key),name,email,phonenumber
```

And other table contains order table(i.e)

```
id,customerid(foreign key),ordervalue,orderdate
```

I need to get the list of customers who have not ordered for last one month(i.e) for the month of august. How can i do it.

This is the query i tried

```
select a.id,a.name,b.order_date from customers a
left join orders b
on a.id = b.customer_id
where b.order_date is null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will extract those customers who haven't order `past one month from today`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM   customers a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
        FROM   orders b
        WHERE  b.cid = a.id AND 
        orderdate BETWEEN now()- '1 month'::interval
        AND now());
```

Here is the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8d0fd/14)

However, if you want to be more precise where you want last month's orders i.e. from `1st of last month to last date of last month` then you can use this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM   customers a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
        FROM   orders b
        WHERE  b.cid = a.id AND 
        to_char(orderdate, 'Mon YYYY') = 
                  to_char(now()- '1 month'::interval, 'Mon YYYY') );
```

Here is the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8d0fd/24)

**EDIT**

Please also have a look at [Roman Pekar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18557777/2555580) answer which is more efficient.

Comment: Ok today is `sep 1` i need to fetch till `31 august` how can i modify it

Comment: You don't need to modify it, the second query will do exactly that! check the sql fiddle.

Comment: @RelicSet don't use to_char to compare dates, it prevents of using indexes on orderdate - see execution plans and execution duration of this query and my query here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2b255/1 (you have to wait a bit, until 1mln records inserted into table)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM orders nx
    WHERE nx.customer_id = c.id
    AND nx.order_date BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-31'
    );
```

Comment: Yes. it makes is easier to read ,and the OP's problem appears to be in the anti-join, not in the range selection. It could be changed to make it depend on the current date, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have indexes on `orderdate` and want this indexes to be used, I suggest to use this query ([date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function is handy to find first day of current month and first day of previous month):

```
select c.id, c.name
from customers as c
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from orders as o
        where
            o.cid = c.id and
            o.orderdate >= date_trunc('month', (now() - '1 month'::interval)::timestamp) and
            o.orderdate < date_trunc('month', now()::timestamp)
    )
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8d0fd/22)

Comparing this one with snyder's answer, it's clear why it's bad practice to use functions on columns before comparing it to filter values.

Here's [**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2b255/1) with two queries. Execution plans are:

This query:

```
Nested Loop Anti Join (cost=0.02..2598.74 rows=160 width=222)
-> Seq Scan on customers c (cost=0.00..13.20 rows=320 width=222)
-> Index Only Scan using ix_orders on orders o (cost=0.02..8.07 rows=1 width=4)
Index Cond: ((cid = c.id) AND (orderdate >= date_trunc('month'::text, ((now() - '1 mon'::interval))::timestamp without time zone)) AND (orderdate < date_trunc('month'::text, (now())::timestamp without time zone)))
```

snyder's:

```
Hash Anti Join (cost=30468.50..30523.40 rows=160 width=222)
Hash Cond: (a.id = b.cid)
-> Seq Scan on customers a (cost=0.00..13.20 rows=320 width=222)
-> Hash (cost=30406.00..30406.00 rows=5000 width=4)
-> Seq Scan on orders b (cost=0.00..30406.00 rows=5000 width=4)
Filter: (to_char((orderdate)::timestamp with time zone, 'Mon YYYY'::text) = to_char((now() - '1 mon'::interval), 'Mon YYYY'::text))
```